# Algorithm: non-Articulation vertex

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graph

> An articulation vertex of a graph G is a vertex whose deletion
>   disconnects G. Let G be a graph with n vertices and m edges. Give a
>   simple O(n + m) algorithm for finding a vertex of G that is not an
>   articulation vertex—i.e. , whose deletion does not disconnect G.

let initial no. of vertices be n, then after removing a vertex,we should have n-1 edges.
I used dfs to traverse the graph and count the no. of vertices. If the count is less than n-1, it is a articulation vertex, so i add it back.
else it is not and i  increase a counter.

what better way to find non articulation vertex since this method is very slow and i need O(n+m).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using DFS (Depth First Search) is a great way to start because by itself it is already an O(V + E). So the idea is to traverse the graph once and be able to figure out its properties. Side note: whenever doing Graph Algorithms *think* **cycles**!

The conditions (under the mindset of DFS) that justify an **articulation vertex**:

1. *Root node* is an articulation point **iff** it has more than one child
2. *Leaf* is never an articulation point
3. *Non-leaf, non-root node* `u` is an articulation point **iff** no non-tree edge goes above `u` from a sub-tree below some child of `u`

This covers all the cases: root node, leaves, and any other node in between.

---

For a **non-articulation vertex**, we just need to find the conditions that justify the opposite:

1. *Root node* is a non-articulation point **iff** it has one child
2. *Leaf* is always a non-articulation point
3. *Non-leaf, non-root node* `u` is an non-articulation point **iff** there is a non-tree edge goes above `u` from a sub-tree below some child of `u`

Number 3 can be read as: if there is a another connection between the two split trees by node `u`, *a.k.a.* a cycle.

---

[Here is some **articulation vertex** code](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/). You might want to tweak it.

Comment: Excellent answer. I would have just said that you run a DFS from somewhere and if you find an edge that goes to a "visited" node, then that visited node (or the one where you are) can be returned as an answer. +1